# Integrate external dialogs with CKEditor Widgets

Tags: javascript, dialog, widget, ckeditor

At work we have a popup dialog system that i would like to use to edit the contents of a widget in CKEditor. Is there any way of going about this?

Does CKEditor have a way of calling outside and get a callback setting values on the Widget?

I have googled it for quite a while now with no success :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When widget is being edited (on its initialisation, on doubleclick, on enter and when the `widget.edit()` method was called), then the [`widget#edit`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget-event-edit) event is fired. The start of the code inside the `widget.edit` method looks like this:

```
edit: function() {
    var evtData = { dialog: this.dialog };

    // Edit event was blocked or there's no dialog to be automatically opened.
    if ( this.fire( 'edit', evtData ) === false || !evtData.dialog )
        return false;

    ...
}
```

This means that if the event was cancelled or there's no dialog name set in the [`widget.definition`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition) (your case, I guess), then after the event was fired nothing will happen.

So, to start, listen on the `widget#edit` event and show your dialog. Then, when the user presses "OK" button use `widget.setData()`. You also need to fire the `editor#saveSnapshot` event before and after doing any changes.

Also, read the documentation of the [`widget.repository#finalizeCreation`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-method-finalizeCreation) method which will let you handle widget creation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it looks promising. How exactly would i go about listening to the widget#edit event? I am having a hard time catching it.

Comment: You can add listeners to the `edit` event in your widget's `init` callback. That's the most convenient way. If, for some reasons, you need to do this from "outside" then you can listen on `editor.widgets#instanceCreated` and then add that listener.

Comment: When i return false on edit, after opening my custom dialog, the widget is not added to the dom. How can i add it to the dom?

Comment: Oh, no i didnt. would widget.getContainer be sufficient for parameter

Comment: There's no such method, so I'm not sure what you mean. The simplest what you can do is passing `widget.wrapper.getParent()` as the docs mention.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, but i am getting widget.wrapper.getParent() as null. Any idea?